How do a article compare images of different resolution using MSE and SSIM?
I have come across an article in the field of medical image processing using super-resolution (SR) where the author is comparing a low-resolution (LR) image with its super-resolution (SR), high-resolution (HR), and bicubic interpolation (BI) counterparts, which sound weird. Nothing is stated as to how this is done, and what kind of interpolation is used.
The article states that

"The proposed SR image was compared against the HR target and a bicubic interpolation (BI) in image space from the LR image".

This is all fine, but they have a figure showing the comparison of the LR image to the HR image. Meaning they have calculated the pixel-to-pixel errors from two images of different resolution. They use a retrospective cohort and in that case state that:

"LR images and HR images come from the same acquisition."

The only way i can make sense of this is if they interpolated the LR image they have down sampled already (because they use a retrospective cohort of medical images). But that is exactly what they did with the bicubic interpolation. Or did they rather just down sampled the HR image to an LR image and made the comparison there.
So my question is: How do they compare the LR image to its original HR target, in the results section?
Can you figure out what they are doing?

Yes, that makes no sense. You will have to ask the authors what they did. If the paper didn’t say, they’re the only ones that know. Papers always have contact information for the authors. The first author is usually the one that did the work and will be able to explain.
